# RabbitMQ Ack for publisher

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I have a problem with RabbitMQ when docker container stops. I have a code:

```
_channel.BasicPublish(messageTopicName, String.Empty, null, stream.ToArray());
```

RabbitMQ is hosted by docker (the default RabbitMQ docker image). The problem arise when I stop this container but my application still sends messages. It is able to send thousands messages before it recognise that the connection is lost. Is there a possibility to check if the message was delivered to the queue?

Comment: Not sure, but do you mean you want something like publisher confirms? https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-seven-java.html

Comment: Wow, this was so easy. Thanks!